# How to update the FlatList dynamically in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Initially loading data from API to FlatList using setState and it loaded perfectly. But I have to perform some actions like create, update & delete of FlatList row. When I try to add new data to the FlatList, the data is not rendered in FlatList with an updated one, but In API it's updated.

How to re-render the flatlist after updating to the API and load the new data to FLatList?

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        faqs: [],

    }

    this.loadFaq();

 };
```

To load the data to FlatList from the API:

```
 loadFaq = async () => {
    let resp = await this.props.getFaqGroup();
    if (resp.faqs) {
        
        console.log(resp.faqs)
        this.setState({
            faqs: resp.faqs,
            // refresh: !this.state.refresh
        })

    }

   };
```

To add new data to API:

```
 createFaqGroup = async (name) => {
    let resp = await this.props.createFaqGroup(name);
    // console.log("resp", resp)
    // this.setState({
    //     refresh: !this.state.refresh
    // })
    // this.forceUpdate();

    this.closePanel();

}
```

FlatList code:

```
    {this.state.faqs && <FlatList
                    extraData={this.state.faqs}
                    horizontal={false}
                    data={this.state.faqs}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 75 }}

                    renderItem={({ item: faqs }) => {

                        return <Card gotoQuestionList={this.gotoQuestionList} key={faqs._id} faqs={faqs} openPanel={(selectedFaq) => this.openPanel({ name: selectedFaq.name, id: selectedFaq._id })} deletePanel={(selectedFaq) => this.deletePanel({ name: selectedFaq.name, id: selectedFaq._id, isPublished: selectedFaq.isPublished })}></Card>
                    }

                    }
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
                />}
```

this.props.createFaqGroup function code:

```
export const createFaqGroup = (name) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    data: { "name": name },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${store.getState().auth.info.token}`
    }
};
return async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('url::', options)
    try {
        let url = `${config.baseUrl}${config.faqUrl}`;
        let resp = await axios(url, options);
       
        console.log(resp.data)
        return resp && resp.data ? resp.data : null;
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error)
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
            dispatch({
                type: type.ERROR,
                data: error.response.data
            });
        } else {
            dispatch({
                type: type.CREATE_FAQ_GROUP_ERROR,
                error: error.message
            });
        }
    }
 };

}
```

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: Have you tried just with extraData={this.state} ? Also are the updated response changed in state? Pls provide any debug logs

Answer (score 1):

Flatlist will update automatically when you set your state i.e by using this.setState() function, it means whenever any changes made to your state variable it will rerender your flatlist. if you still face the same problem remove your **this.state.faqs && part**, this looks unnecessary because there is no need to check if you are passing the empty array to faltlist or not, flatlist allows you to pas empty array as well, it will not give you any error.

Comment: Any sample on this. I'm new to react native

Answer (score 1):

I think you should load data again, after you add them, so you can modify your function **createFaqGroup** like this:

```
createFaqGroup = async (name) => {
  let resp = await this.props.createFaqGroup(name);
  this.loadFaq();

  this.closePanel();
}
```

Comment: if I load again it shows recently added data only.

Comment: Can I see this.props.crateFaqGroup function, because I think you may mutate the state, and thats why not re-rendering

Comment: this.props.createFaqGroup is api function.

Comment: i have updated the this.props.createFaqGroup function to question. kindly check it out

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
createFaqGroup = async (name) => {
  let resp = await this.props.createFaqGroup(name);
  this.setState({faqs: [...this.state.faqs, name]})

  this.closePanel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still facing the same issue. It shows a single row in the FlatList.